# ModuleNotFoundError When Importing Custom Django App Modules

Tags: django, exception, import, module

I'm currently trying to create a custom django app within my project. I'm attempting to access some of the models from another directory within the same project but I am unable to import anything from my app's modules.

I've looked into numerous issues here on Stackoverflow and have had no luck with any of them. I've tried editing my sys.path manually. And I've tried messing around with my settings.py file as well.

Current Directory: https://gyazo.com/fe75655bd3296c47aaa36f5a10c92dfb

I'm trying to run the following import within the `bot` directory within my `titandash` application.

```py
from titanbot.titandash.models.queue import Queue
```

The fix I tried with my `sys.path` looks like this:

```py
import os
import sys

cwd = os.getcwd().split("\\")

if cwd not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("\\".join(cwd))
if cwd[:-1] not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("\\".join(cwd[:-1]))

sys.path.append("\\".join(cwd + ["titandash"]))
```

I expect for my modules to be importable from either directory back and forth for use in other places.

```
  File "C:\Users\Brett\repos\tt2_py\titanbot\titandash\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import dashboard, project_settings
  File "C:\Users\Brett\repos\tt2_py\titanbot\titandash\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .utils import start
  File "C:\Users\Brett\repos\tt2_py\titanbot\titandash\utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models.queue import Queue
  File "C:\Users\Brett\repos\tt2_py\titanbot\titandash\models\queue.py", line 6, in <module>
    from titandash.bot.core.bot import grab_functions
  File "C:\Users\Brett\repos\tt2_py\titanbot\titandash\bot\core\bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    from titanbot.titandash.models.queue import Queue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'titanbot.titandash'
```

Note:  This stack is raised when attempting to start my Django server locally `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: The `titandash` directory is in the project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`), so is on the python path. Therefore the import should be `from titandash.models.queue import Queue`, without the `titanbot` prefix.

Comment: This fixed the issue I was running into, thanks @Alasdair. I would note that this happened because I'm using PyCharm as my IDE and it shows the import `from titandash.models.queue import Queue` as incorrect. So it's worth looking into the IDE configuration for imports as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `titandash` directory is in the project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`), so is on the Python path. Therefore the import should be `from titandash.models.queue import Queue`, without the `titanbot` prefix.